# Find $k$ such that $f(k)$ is Minimum

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, functions, definite-integrals

Find $k$ such that

$$f(k)=\int_{0}^{4} |4x-x^2-k|dx$$ is Minimum

I splitted the Modulus in to two cases:

$1.$   if   $4x-x^2-k \ge 0$ Then

$$f(k)=\int_{0}^{4} (4x-x^2-k)dx=\frac{32}{3}-4k$$

$2.$ if   $4x-x^2-k \lt 0$  Then

$$f(k)=4k-\frac{32}{3}$$

But How to minimize $f(k)$ which is linear in $k$?

Comment: completing the square to find x such that the integrand is 0 in terms of k, and then split the integral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to separate it into three cases :

- Case 1 : If $k\ge 4$, then we have $4x-x^2-k=-(x-2)^2+4-k\le 0$, so $$f(k)=\int_0^4 (x^2-4x+k)dx=4k-\frac{32}{3}$$So, $f(k)\ge f(4)=\frac{16}{3}$ for $k\ge 4$.
- Case 2 : If $0\lt k\lt 4$, then $0\lt 2-\sqrt{4-k}\lt 2+\sqrt{4-k}\lt 4$ where $x=2\pm\sqrt{4-k}$ are roots of $4x-x^2-k$, so we have $$\begin{align}\small f(k)&=\int_{0}^{2-\sqrt{4-k}}(x^2-4x+k)dx+\int_{2-\sqrt{4-k}}^{2+\sqrt{4-k}}(-x^2+4x-k)dx+\int_{2+\sqrt{4-k}}^{4}(x^2-4x+k)dx\\\\&=\frac 43\left(2(4-k)^{3/2}+3k-8\right)\end{align}$$
  and
  $$f'(k)=4\left(1-\sqrt{4-k}\right)$$ from which we see that $f(k)$ is decreasing for $0\lt k\lt 3$ and increasing for $3\lt k\lt 4$ to have $f(k)\ge f(3)=4$ for $0\lt k\lt 4$.
- Case 3 : If $k\le 0$, then $4x-x^2-k=x(4-x)-k\ge 0$, so $$f(k)=\int_0^4(-x^2+4x-k)dx=\frac{32}{3}-4k$$So, $f(k)\ge f(0)=\frac{32}{3}$ for $k\le 0$.

Therefore, the minimum of $f(k)$ is attained when $\color{red}{k=3}$.